# Sound does not working in my iphone device( but working good in simulator)

Tags: swift, xcode, audio, uikit, device

### please help me
Sound does not working in my iphone device (But working good in simulator)

import UIKit
import Lottie
import AVFoundation

class SplashViewController: UIViewController {

```
var player: AVAudioPlayer!
var timer: Timer?

@IBOutlet weak var mySplashView: LottieAnimationView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    mySplashView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    mySplashView.loopMode = .loop
    mySplashView.play()
    
    playSound()
    
    //Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5, target: self, selector: #selector(changeVC), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5, target: self, selector: #selector(stopSound), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
}

@objc func stopSound() {
    player?.stop()
    timer?.invalidate()
    
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    vc.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
    self.present(vc, animated: true)
}



func playSound(){
    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "012", withExtension: "mp3")
    player = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url!)
    player!.play()
}
```

}

i wanna listen sound in my device like simulator